# python remove rows with the same keys and keep the row with the most recent date stamp

Tags: python, pandas, automation, pandas-groupby

I have a SharePoint excel sheet with the file name and format that updates every day with the most recent information. The rows are order numbers (as key for other dataframe), ordered qty and received qty for the current day.

Rows will be added if there are more orders placed today, and old orders will be deleted after they are fulfilled for several days to keep the size of this report relatively small. It looks like this

[image]

What I want to do is to have a Python program or Power BI one to generate another excel file and refresh it automatically. This generated file will keep all the distinct PO numbers (like a groupby in SQL or pivot in excel) but only keep the record of the most recent days.

For example, if files on 1/2/2021 and 1/3/2021 looks like this:

[image]

For example,

[image]

Then the generated file on 1/3 will look like:

[image]

Just keep only one row for all the distinct POs and this row will be the ones on the most recent days in the report.

Comment: Do you have a specific question? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score -1):

In python you can compare strings based of their lexicographic order so
if we look at the logical expression

```
'A' < 'B'
```

this comparison will result in True.
So then you could write a function which will sort out the biggest one with the same dates using this functionallity.

Also if you formulate your dates as `"2020-02-14"` / `YYYY-MM-DD` then you can also use string comparison to find out which date is older or newer or in other words bigger or smaller.

For writing and reading you could use python CSV librarys as I understood you are working with .csv files but in my opinion these librarys aren't actually that helpful because you can also implement the same functionallity in python quite easily, but it comes down to what you prefer.